# Find a non injective function between a set of integers and itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a set of integers:
$ A = \left\{1,2,6,8\right\}$ is there any way to find a non-injective function that when fed any of the numbers in $A$ gives another number in $A$ (Basically a non-injective surjection between $A$ and itself)

EDIT: To clarify, set $A$ is an example. I want to know a general algorithm for determining a function to do this with any set.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I meant surjection. I edited.

Comment: pigeonhole principle implies this is impossible

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is finite, you cannot do this. The reason is that if $A$ is a finite set, then $f\colon A\to A$ is injective if and only if it is surjective if and only if it is bijective.

If you just look for a non-injective function without fixed points (namely, it never satisfies $f(x)=x$), you can do it granted $A$ has at least two elements.

Pick $a,b\in A$ and define $f(x)=\begin{cases} a & x\neq a\\ b & x=a\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget "injective" and "surjective" for a moment. It sounds as if the thing you want might be this:

(a) for every $a \in A$, we have $f(a) \ne a$, and

(b) for every $a \in A$, there's some element $p$ with $f(p) = a$.

The second of these is called "surjectivity," but the first is not called "non injectivity" --- I'm not sure that it has a name.

In general, the answer is "yes" (except in one special case). One solution breaks into five cases:

1. $A$ is empty. The vacuous function satisfies both conditions.
2. $A$ has one element: then there's only one function from $A$ to $A$, and it satisfies condition (b), but not condition (a).
3. $A$ is finite, nonempty Then number the elements in increasing order, so that
   $$
   a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \ldots < a_k
   $$
   for some $k \ge 2$. Define $f(a_1) = a_2, f(a_2) = a_3, \ldots, f(a_{k-1}) = a_k$, and $f(a_k) = a_1$.
4. $A$ is infinite, but bounded below (i.e., it has a least element). Again, place the elements in increasing order, and define
   $$
   f(a_1) = a_2, f(a_2) = a_1 \\
   f(a_3) = a_4, f(a_4) = a_3 \\
   ...
   $$
   and so on.  The case where $A$ is infinite but  bounded above is similar.
5. $A$ is infinite, but neither bounded below nor above. Again, the elements of $A$ can be ordered by "less than"; define $f$ to send each element $a\in A$ to the next higher element of $A$ (much as in case 3, but without the "wrap around" for the "last" element)).